# Solr cloud 6.2 delete collection doesn't delete its config

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm using solr 6.2 and we're currently working on creating a schema which meets our requirements. We'll be using managed schema for that so we can add fields without a full cluster restart.

The problem happen when we want to delete the collection (to recreate the schema from scratch): Solr seem to keep the config files (including hte managed-schema one). We then have a lot of errors "Field ... already exists"

Following image is what I have in the admin panel after I have deleted the collection.

[image: No collection, but some leftover config]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuration has a separate API entry point. If you want to delete a particular configSet you have to curl to this URL

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/configs?action=DELETE&name=myConfigSet
```

More info: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/ConfigSets+API